# Create a rounded SVG rectangle with multiple borders?

Tags: svg

In XAML there is the concept of a [Border] object that behaves much like an SVG rectangle except that a XAML [Border] can contain a child element.

So I could create a [Border] with a black stroke and inside it have another border that had a white stroke and a fill of Green.

This gives the the look of a single rectangle with both a black border & then an inner white border.

How can you create this in SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multiple paths. In this particular case you could 'cheat' by having the same path twice, with the lower path having a larger border that appears 'outside' the upper object; in general, though you will need to create paths with offsets if you want this behavior.

Comment: A `<use>` element can help with that, so you don't need to repeat the path as much, just use with a different 'stroke-width'.